# How to remotely open mac desktop from PC

Tags: mac, vmware

I have installed Mac OS X on a Virtual Machine. I want to use remote desktop to view it but there is no option in OS X to enable remote desktop.

Is there any way to do using Vmware workstation or in the OS X operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X has a built in remote technology called [Apple Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Remote_Desktop).  It is based on the VNC protocol.  If you enable the service you can connect using many VNC clients.

Answer (score 2):

To enable Screen Sharing on Mac OS X, go to *System Preferences* -> *Sharing* then turn on ***Screen Sharing***.

Then you can use any VNC software to control your Mac (the address is *vnc://ip-of-your-mac*).

[image: screen sharing]

Comment: i tried that but when i use vnc it does not connect
when i use simple ip address it says no matching security types and when i use vnc//ip then it says data is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Both!  You can enable VNC access via the Mac or use the VMware client.

Comment: which vmware client?

Comment: The server edition used to come with a client viewer app (much like a VNC client.)  However, i haven't used VMware in some time and I don't see a reference to the client app on their site. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I enjoy using http://logmein.com. OSX does have VNC abilities built in however the interface for logmein.com couldn't be easier. Once you setup your account you install a little piece of software that runs in the background. Then you can log into the logmein.com site from any computer and login to your mac from there. I can't live without it!

Comment: i tried that an dit good , i was able to login remotely on mac, but i want it from from PC which is on same network , the cost is too much

Comment: They have a free version that you don't have to pay for. I've been using logmein.com for a couple years at no cost.

Comment: OS X does have VNC capabilities built-in as demonstrated by some of the other users.